# Load and display image one by one from URL and Cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage library to display images in my scrollview with page control.

How to download image one by one and display it. Suppose i have 4 URL : url1,url2,url3,url4
so i want to display url1 first then...2,3,4..so on...2,3,4 should load in background until the are not download a placeholder image show there.

Below is my code of inside for loop i try is it perfect ?

```
        NSString* serverImgicon=<url here in a loop>;
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString: serverImgicon];
            //set your image on main thread.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                [img sd_setImageWithURL:url
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderImg"]];
            });
        });
```

Comment: follow this answer [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342172/load-images-using-sdwebimage-in-order)

Comment: if images should load in background then what is the purpose of loading one by one..

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, it'll work fine

```
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        CollectionViewCell *cell =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        myobject *newobject = _myarray[indexPath.item];
        cell.nameLabel.text =newobject.name;

          dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

            [cell.activityIndicatorForImage startAnimating];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                                     [NSURL URLWithString:newobject.image]]];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if(image!= nil){
                    [[cell myimage] setImage:image];
                    [cell.activityIndicatorForImage setHidden:NO];

                }else{
                    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PLACEHOLDER"];
                    [[cell myimage] setImage:image];
                    [cell.activityIndicatorForImage setHidden:YES];
                    [cell.activityIndicatorForImage stopAnimating];

                }


                [cell setNeedsLayout];
            });
        });

        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

use  sdwebCache to load images asynchronously

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

/******************/

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

then load images like this :

```
NSArray *tempArray = [stickersThumbRecords objectForKey:collectioName];

                if (tempArray.count>indexPath.item) {
                    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] ];

                    [imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderFrame"]];
                }
```

Comment: ajjjjjj i am doing same thing...did you check ...my question is to load and display image in order of 1 by 1...

Comment: for low connection like 2g...its download in synch image random image from URL...means URL1 is empty and URL2 have image and so on...

Comment: you cannot serialise the download, i think you should use CollectionView instead Scrollview to Download images that only request the download for visible cells